# div with float next to div with width

Tags: css, width

I have html:

```
<div class="field-label"><label>Email: </label></div>
<div class="field"><input class="input" ......></div>
```

and piece of css:

```
.field-label  { clear:left; float:left; padding:0.5em; width:6em;  }
.field { padding:0.5em; }
```

And it worked fine. But for some elements I wanted to apply following change:
when I add **width** to **.field** class layout goes to blazes: element with **.field** class appears under element with field-label class. Container of whole form is width enough to hold elements with **field-label** & **field** class.

Why is it happening, did I miss something in css basics?

Thanks ,Pawel

Comment: You should add float: left also to .field, together with width: ...

Comment: Thanks. Yeap I did just sec ago and it worked fine. However I'm curious why explicit width break above layout.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take into account that padding, margin etc. is not included in width?

Comment: Yes I did, container is about 600px, whereas both field & field-label have about 300px in width.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't take into account the width of the .field-label : 
http://yfrog.com/fvstyleqj

Comment: Container width should be bigger than field width + field-label width + field-label padding (+possibly field padding; I think floats can overlap that but I'm not sure). Also mixing absolute and relative lengths is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using spans instead of divs for this layout, as spans are inline elements they might behave better than divs. Also, do you have a live example?

Answer (score 0):

If the label and the field should appear on one line, you have to have a  around the two 's witn an explicit width wide enought to contain the two others.